# Como detectar un click en una matriz de botones en Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Miren, yo tengo una matriz de botones que obviamente la creo dentro del "Codigo de Java", implemento la clase de `View.OnClickListener` y dentro del metodo onClick(View view) tengo lo siguiente:

```
public void onClick(View view){ 
          for (int x = 0; x < btnMatriz.length; x++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < btnMatriz[x].length; i++) {
                    switch (view.getId()) {
                            case /** */: //Mi problema es aqui, no se como obtener el id del boton al que le di click, normalmente va R.id.idDelBoton, pero en este caso la matriz de botones no se ubican en dentro del activity_main, sino que dentro del "Codigo de Java" incluso he intentado con case btnMatriz[x][i].getId() y masbien me tira un error

                              break;


                    }
                }
            }}
```

me gustaria que me pudieran ayudar, como conseguir el id del elemento, al menos quisiera saber si lo estoy haciendo bien.

Comment: por que eso estra dentro del evento onClick? que es lo que harás con los botones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que despues de que generas tu matriz de botones, los colocas en algún lado de la UI. si es asi y si creaste los botones programaticamente, no necesitas obtener su ID para darles un evento como onClick.

El Id de un elemento sirve para identificarlo cuando este fue creado a través de un layout, como los creaste programaticamente, tienes la referencia directa a los botones es por esto que no lo necesitas.

puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
for (int x = 0; x < btnMatriz.length; x++) {
   for (int i = 0; i < btnMatriz[x].length; i++) {
             btnMatriz[x][i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){
                   public void onClick(View view){ 
                         //haces lo que necesites
                   }  
              });   
   }  
}
```

Esto lo puedes hacer, dentro de tu método onCreate o donde tu necesites que se asignen.

Comment: Gracias amigo, me sacaste de una gran duda, por cierto, la manera en la que me dices que le agrege el onClickListener ya la conocia, lo que queria saber es como saber a que boton le doy click en el metodo onClick de la interfaz View.OnClickListener, que por cierto trate y trate y resulto ser de la siguiente manera: if(view == btnMatriz[x][i]){/**Codigo **/}, pero al final lo hice como me has dicho.